# something is missing in my contact form dropbox validation php or javascript

Tags: php, ajax, forms, dropbox, contacts

here are my html, php, and script. 
I receive every information correctly in email except for estimate which is dropbox form. Can somebody take a look at my script?

thanks

```js
< script >
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById('companyname').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "empty";
      return false;
    }
    x = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Email cannot be empty";
      return false;
    } else {
      var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (!re.test(x)) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Email format invalid";
        return false;
      }
    }
    x = document.getElementById('address').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "empty";
      return false;
    }
    x = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "empty";
      return false;
    }
    x = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "empty";
      return false;
    }
    x = document.getElementById('estimate').value;
    if (x == "") {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "empty";
      return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
    formData = {
      'companyname': $('input[name=companyname]').val(),
      'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
      'address': $('input[name=address]').val(),
      'phone': $('input[name=phone]').val(),
      'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
      'estimate': $('input[name=estimate]').val(),
    };


    $.ajax({
      url: "mail.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $('#status').text(data.message);
        if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
          $('#contact-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#status').text(jqXHR);
      }
    });


  } <
  /script>
```

```css
<?php
$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$estimate = $_POST['estimate'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($companyname === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
}
if ($email === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
} else {
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email format invalid.', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
  }
}
if ($address === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'empty', 'code' => 0));
  exit();
}
if ($phone === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'empty', 'code' => 0));
 exit();
}
if ($name === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'empty', 'code' => 0));
 exit();
}
if ($estimate === ''){
  print json_encode(array('message' => 'empty', 'code' => 0));
 exit();
}
$content="From: $companyname \nEmail: $email \nAddress: $address \nPhone: $phone \nName: $name \nEstimate: $estimate";
$recipient = "info@itnecommerce.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email successfully sent!', 'code' => 1));
exit();
?>
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="companyname"><span style="color: #000">companyname</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="companyname" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="companyname" placeholder="put company name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address"><span style="color: #000">address</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="address" placeholder="put address.">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email"><span style="color: #000">email</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone"><span style="color: #000">cell</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="phone" placeholder="800-123-4567">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name"><span style="color: #000">name</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" placeholder="put name.">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estimate"><span style="color: #000">estimate</span></label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="estimate" id="estimate">
        <option value="1">$1~$1000</option>
        <option value="2">$1000~$3000</option>
        <option value="3">$3000~$5000</option>
        <option value="4">$5000~$10000</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>                       
</form>
```

here are my html, php, and script. 
I receive every information correctly in email except for estimate which is dropbox form. Can somebody take a look at my script?

thanks

Comment: As far by observation i can see in php script you are missing variable `$subject` or forget to set the value of the variable. AND Second thing is the don't put `$.ajax()` code in the validation function. You script not using the `$.ajax()` block it is getting the value from `action` attribute . I think

Comment: I think by dropbox means you are talking about the `select` drop down list item which is called `estimate` in your script

Comment: thanks for your comments. i tried dropdown because other inputs don't work in my case. other inputs are working fine because this below tutorial helped me but just this dropdown isn't there. can anyone show me how to fix that php in proper way? https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-contact-form/

Comment: thanks for your comments once again. i just realized i put input. all ihad to do was to change that to select since its dropdown. thank you for mentioning select Er. Amit Joshi ;DDD

Comment: Your Welcome. Happy to see you corrected your issue.